# Possible to find parameter type methods return type in Scala where parameter is a primitive type?

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

Suppose I have:

```
class X
{
   val listPrimitive: List[Int] = null
   val listX: List[X] = null
}
```

and I print out the return types of each method in Scala as follows:

```
classOf[ComplexType].getMethods().foreach { m => println(s"${m.getName}: ${m.getGenericReturnType()}") }

listPrimitive: scala.collection.immutable.List<Object> 
listX: scala.collection.immutable.List<X>
```

So... I can determine that the listX's element type is X, but is there any way to determine via reflection that listPrimitive's element type is actually java.lang.Integer? ...

```
val list:List[Int] = List[Int](123);
val listErased:List[_] = list;
println(s"${listErased(0).getClass()}")  // java.lang.Integer
```

NB. This seems not to be an issue due to JVM type erasure since I *can* find the types parameter of List. It looks like the scala compiler throws away this type information IFF the parameter type is java.lang.[numbers] .

UPDATE:

I suspect this type information *is* available, due to the following experiment. Suppose I define:

```
class TestX{
  def f(x:X):Unit = {
    val floats:List[Float] = x.listPrimitive()  // type mismatch error
  }
}
```

and X.class is imported via a jar. The full type information must be available in X.class in order that this case correctly fails to compile.

UPDATE2:

Imagine you're writing a scala extension to a Java serialization library. You need to implement a:

```
def getSerializer(clz:Class[_]):Serializer
```

function that needs to do different things depending on whether:

```
clz==List[Int]   (or equivalently: List[java.lang.Integer])
clz==List[Float] (or equivalently: List[java.lang.Float])
clz==List[MyClass]
```

My problem is that I will only ever see:

```
clz==List[Object]
clz==List[Object]
clz==List[MyClass]
```

because clz is provided to this function as clz.getMethods()(i).getGenericReturnType().

Starting with clz:Class[_] how can I recover the element type information that was lost?

Its not clear to me that TypeToken will help me because its usages:

```
typeTag[T]
```

requires that I provide T (ie. at compile time).

So, one path to a solution... Given some clz:Class[_], can I determine the TypeTokens of its method's return types? Clearly this is possible as this information must be contained (somewhere) in a .class file for a scala compiler to correctly generate type mismatch errors (see above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the java bytecode level `Int`s have to be represented as something else (apparently `Object`) because  a `List` can only contain objects, not primitives. So that's what java-level reflection can tell you. But the scala type information is, as you infer, present (at the bytecode level it's in an annotation, IIRC), so you should be able to inspect it with scala reflection:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

val list:List[Int] = List[Int](123)

def printTypeOf[A: TypeTag](a: A) = println(typeOf[A])

printTypeOf(list)
```

Response to update2: you should use scala reflection to obtain a mirror, not the `Class[_]` object. You can go via the class name if need be:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

val rm = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)

val someClass: Class[_] = ...

val scalaMirrorOfClass = rm.staticClass(someClass.getName)
// or possibly rm.reflectClass(someClass) ?

val someObject: Any = ...

val scalaMirrorOfObject = rm.reflectClass(someObject)
```

I guess if you *really* only have the class, you could create a classloader that only loads that class? I can't imagine a use case where you wouldn't have the class, or even a value, though.

Comment: The objects are represented as java.lang.Integer, sure.
But doesn't TypeTag only apply to objects and types. I'm looking for the return type of a method (which is clearly known to the compiler and available in the class file, somewhere).

Comment: Find that the element type is Int (instead of java.lang.Integer) would also solved my problem. However, this information is missing also.

Comment: I don't understand. `TypeTag` is just a helper for getting a type; if you're inspecting a method return type with scala reflection you can get the same type representation that you'd get from `typeOf`.

Comment: typeOf doesn't help because it requires a [T] type parameter, which I don't have. I'm starting with a Class[_] and would need to back out a TypeTag from the class's method's return type. How can this be done? (I've added UPDATE2, above).

Comment: mirror.classSymbol(clz).toType lets my find the full information. Thanks!